# Adding Street layer to a Satellite map

Tags: layers, mapbox, satellite, openlayers

I am new to openlayers and I am using OpenLayers Version: 6.3.1. 
I need to display a satellite map. I have used mapbox API to display the satellite map. It doesn't have streets and displays only the plain terrain. How do I create a new layer that displays the streets and country/region names with the satellite map?
I have attached my snippet for map below:

```
var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.satellite/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=My_ACCESS_TOKEN'
  })
});

var source = new VectorSource({wrapX: false});

var vector = new VectorLayer({
  source: source
});

var map = new Map({

  layers: [raster, vector],
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    center: [0,0],
    zoom: 0
  })
});
```

Comment: style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9 https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/satellite-map/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To combine satellite and streets in a single raster layer:

```
var raster = new TileLayer({
  source: new ol.source.XYZ({
    url: 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-streets-v10/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=My_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    tileSize: 512
  })
});
```

Comment: Don't use MapBox much but nice to know about the satellite-streets option

Comment: Why is that so @Greg? Just asking.